# How to handle large selection sets when paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, server-side

I'm working on a document management platform. Users can upload documents to the web app, edit their meta-data, and execute tasks (e.g. send the documents to their recipients by e-mail).

Our users need to be able to select any number of documents from a search result. They can pick documents one by one, or click a "Select all" button. We could be talking about thousands or tens of thousands documents to be selected.

When searching for documents, we display paged results in a Datatables table. This means that when making a selection of documents for a task, we need to stock the selection set somewhere, since the Datatable only has knowledge of the rows that are being currently displayed. Currently, we stock the documents' GUIDS in a hidden page element.

This is proving to be insufficient, because we're facing problems with this approach:
- When selecting all documents, there might be a concurrency issue. What if more documents are uploaded that fit the current search criteria, between the time a user makes a search and plans a task? This could lead to the unintended processing of documents.
- If you send all GUIDs to the client when they choose "Select all" (to avoid the concurrency issue above), the list might be too large to send as a JSON object.
- The opposite might also happen: what if the list on the client's side is too large to send to the server?

My question is: what is a better approach to stocking and processing large user selection sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out you can compress response data in ASP.Net, [making use of GZip or Deflate](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/apr/28/gzipdeflate-compression-in-aspnet-mvc).
Thanks to this, I was able to send large data sets, no problem.